# Query based on menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a menu (categories) set on wordpress and I would like to create query´s based on the categories on that menu, one query per menu item

- menu item 1
- menu item 2
- menu item 3
- menu item 4

  $args = array( 'category_name' => 'menu item 1');

  $args = array( 'category_name' => 'menu item 2');

  $args = array( 'category_name' => 'menu item 3');

  $args = array( 'category_name' => 'menu item 4');

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're speaking about ordinary WP menu system, you can grab the menu data by it's location like this:

```
function custom_menu_output( $theme_location ) {
    if ( ($theme_location) && ($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations[$theme_location]) ) {
        $menu = get_term( $locations[$theme_location], 'nav_menu' );
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
        foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
            $args = array( 'category_name' => $menu_item->title);
            //Do your query here & everything else
        }
    }
}
```